# Why doesn't np.load(f, allow_pickle=True) return the original objects?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, serialization, pickle

I'd like to store numpy arrays in a compressed .npz file, along with some metadata, which are in a `dict`:

```
import numpy as np

D = {}
D["a"] = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
D["b"] = {1: 2, "3": "hey"}
np.savez_compressed("test.npz", **D)

x = np.load("test.npz", allow_pickle=True)
a = x["a"]
print(a, type(a))
b = x["b"]
print(b, type(b))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'> instead of <class 'dict'>!
print(b["3"])      # can't access to b["3"]!
```

**Why doesn't `x["3"]` give access to the original dictionary?** but a `numpy.ndarray` object instead?

Comment: You can get the dictionary out of `b` with `b.item()`.

Comment: @sj95126 Thanks, I think you can post it as an answer. Why is this additional function call needed, is it documented in np.load (I didn't find this)?

Comment: `np.save` saves a numpy array.  If you give it something else, it first does `np.asarray(obj)`.  That's what `np.load` returns - the `dict` wrapped in an array.  If you want to save the `dict` directly, use `pickle`.

Comment: I'll have to deter to @hpaulj on this. I can't find the right documentation references that explain this accurately and I don't want to post an incomplete answer.

Comment: The `np.save`, `savez` and `load` talk repeatedly about saving/returning arrays.  They don't explicitly say what happens when an argument is not an array.  But `np.save` uses `array like`,  which is the same phrase used by `np.array` to describe its input.

Comment: It makes sense @hpaulj. You can probably post this as answer!